# How do i read only a specific line of a .text file? Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print line by line from a text file, i don't want to print all lines at once. I need to can print only the first line, or only the second one etc...

Comment: stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Help by voting and accepting answer if its works

Answer (score -1):

To print the n-th line, you can just advance by n-1 lines before printing a line. Note that this has linear runtime (i.e. ok if you want to print just a single line, but if you want to print several lines it'll get slow).

```
def get_nth_line(fobj, n):
    for i in range(n):
        next(fobj)
    return next(fobj)

# print third line:
with open("my_file.txt") as f:
    print(get_nth_line(f, 2))
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is code :

```py
filename = "geek.txt"
lines = tuple(open(filename, 'r')) 

print(lines)
print(lines[1])
```